# How do I embed an if/then statement on HTML

Tags: javascript

First off, I am a newbie to javascript, so if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

I work in a place that issues asset tags to equipment in a chronological manner. I wish to create a widget in our internal webpage that would allow the user to input that asset tag number and have a result presented to them that gives a range (six month range) of when that equipment was purchased and by that end give a result of how old that equipment is. "Your equipment was purchased in the first half of 2011. It is now two years old."

I have the formula figured out in Excel with a huge IF statement, and I also have created a standalone .exe file with AutoIt. However, how do I get this script to work within a web page?

Basically here is the range of numbers and dates. I can include the AutoIt script if that would help...

```
<45669 - "Seven years or older"
>45670 - "First half of 2007. Purchased 7 years ago."
>43600 - "Second half of 2007. Purchased 6.5 years ago."
>47320 - "First half of 2008. Purchased 6 years ago."
>48000 - "Second half of 2008. Purchased 5.5 years ago."
>48440 - "First half of 2009. Purchased 5 years ago."
>48970 - "Second half of 2009. Purchased 4.5 years ago."
>49800 - "First half of 2010. Purchased 4 years ago."
>50250 - "Second half of 2010. Purchased 3.5 years ago."
>52100 - "First half of 2011. Purchased 3 years ago."
>52950 - "Second half of 2011. Purchased 2.5 years ago."
>53625 - "First half of 2012. Purchased 2 years ago."
>53900 - "Second half of 2012. Purchased 1.5 years ago."
>54220 - "First half of 2013. Purchased 1 year ago."
>54770 - "Second half of 2013. Purchased 6 months ago."
>55680 - "First half of 2014. Purchased less than 6 months ago."
```

Comment: What does Excel and/or a random .exe file have to do with a web page?

Comment: Can you post your excel function?  Ideally, you would have a form on your page that says `give me a number`.  When the submit button is clicked, Javascript can request data from your server.

Comment: You realise that this approach looks like you're going to be doing a lot of work every six months when you need to update things.

Comment: Lots of maintenance work...why not just compare the current date to the purchase date and round the years? "This equipment was purchased *x* years again on <give date here>" -- so much less upkeep -- Also, you'll need to use AJAX if you want this to work with no page refresh.

Comment: What are these numbers `45669` and `52100` and `55680` - do they stand for autogenereted ids, or do they enode a date?

Comment: Matt - We have an internal webpage and I would like the users to be able to query that age of the equipment there.

Comment: Kyle - Would I set up a database for JavaScript to query?
David - Yes I do know this. That is why I am appealing to people who know more than I to help me.
tymeJV - AJAX... Google here I come...
341613 - They are not autogenerated. These are the sequential numbers that were issued for the equipment. But I know when they were issued, thus I know the age of the equipment.